# Redirection after running js

Tags: javascript, html, push-notification

How to make a redirect after the script execution of the subscription to push notification?

```
<script>
      var OneSignal = window.OneSignal || [];
      OneSignal.push(function() {
        OneSignal.init({
          appId: "*****-*****-*****-*****-*****",
      });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this ?

```
OneSignal.push(["init", {
/* Your other init options here */
welcomeNotification: {
    "title": "My Custom Title",
    "message": "Thanks for subscribing!",
    // "url": "" /* Provide your URL */
}}]);
```

[Source](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/web-push-custom-code-examples)

Comment: I need a redirect right after the subscription. this does not work

var OneSignal = window.OneSignal || [];
      OneSignal.push(["init", {
            appId: "",
        welcomeNotification: {
            "title": "My Custom Title",
            "message": "Thanks for subscribing!",
            "url": "http://yandex.ru"
        }}]);

Comment: What error are you getting in your debugger/ console?